# Fault in one vue component prevents all from working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am developing a Laravel + vuejs app. I use Laravel mix to manage the component registration etc. I have a number of vue components for various parts of my application

In one of them, I have this line that causes an error

```
 this.map.on('dragend',function(){console.log('Dragend Event')})
```

That produces this error:

```
bundle.js:53526 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

Laravel mix does not error on build, this error only appears at runtime

Now, the error itself is not that big a deal. I can fix it what worries me is that because Laravel mix bundles all the components together it means that no component is now working

Every page I visit has the same issue. is there a way to segregate out the components.

So if I have a failure on a component how to I make sure it only affects the page where those components are needed? and not the whole site.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a separate js for each page which contains only the components for the current page.

Comment: I'd say this  is how javascript in general works.Your script comes to an error and stops execution. That's why you typically have a lot of null checks. Try Catch could solve your specific error - or you just go for save checks at multiple places

Comment: @FrankProvost it is not the error that is the issue, it is the fallout.

Comment: @thefallen i guess that is one way, I will see if mix can produce seperate files for grouped components. so that i can still load the main bundled js

Comment: You can do `mix.js('file1').js('file2')` and extract vendor libraries like vue and jquery in a separate file.

Comment: I have huge doubts that this will solve any problem. Splitting vendor from your files will still cause your scripts to stop working if you implement an error. This is a script language that simply stops on errors that you don't catch. Either catch them or ensure they don't accor. The shown specific problem is so easy to resolve - simply check that this.map is existing before assinging events to it

Comment: @FrankProvost it really isn't about the error, there are many things we could do to prevent that and countless other errors happening, but if we make a mistake. we could take out a whole site. So I get defensive coding should be the norm, but I prefer a belt and braces approach. Thanks